# What is the formula for the sum of $^{n}C_{k}$ for fixed $k$ and varying $n$?

Tags: combinatorics

I am searching for a formula of sum of binomial coefficients $^{n}C_{k}$ where $k$ is fixed but $n$ varies in a given range? Does any such formula exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/399213), we have the formula
$$
\sum_{j=k}^{n-m}\binom{j}{k}\binom{n-j}{m}=\binom{n+1}{k+m+1}
$$
If we set $m=0$, we get
$$
\sum_{j=k}^n\binom{j}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?
$$\sum_{n=k}^m {n\choose k}={m+1\choose {k+1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{n_{1} \geq n_{0}}$ and the identity
$\ds{{m \choose s}
     \equiv
     \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\ }{\pars{1 + z}^{m} \over z^{s + 1}}
     \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,,\quad s = 0,1,2,3,\ldots}$:

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ n_{0}}^{n_{1}}{n \choose k}}
> =\sum_{n\ =\ n_{0}}^{n_{1}}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\ }{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}}{1 \over z^{k + 1}}\sum_{n\ =\ n_{0}}^{n_{1}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\ }{1 \over z^{k + 1}}
> \pars{1 + z}^{n_{0}}\,{\pars{1 + z}^{n_{1} - n_{0} + 1} - 1 \over \pars{1 + z} - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\ }{\pars{1 + z}^{n_{1} + 1} \over z^{k + 2}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> -\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\ }{\pars{1 + z}^{n_{0}} \over z^{k + 2}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ n_{0}}^{n_{1}}{n \choose k}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{n_{1} + 1 \choose k + 1} - {n_{0} \choose k + 1}}
$$

Comment: Something must be wrong: when $n_0=k$ and $n_1=m$ we recover hyergeometric's answer but with an extra $-\binom k{k+1}$.

Comment: @EricStucky $\displaystyle{k \choose k + 1} = 0$. Thanks.

Comment: It's great how after doing combinatorics for the last six years [admittedly on and off] I still forget which number is supposed to be bigger :/